# Calling a ServiceStack service from Razor

Tags: servicestack

A bit of an edge case here:
I need to call a servicestack service from razor (same website)
Right now I'm doing

```
CheckIfConfiguredResponse aResponse= new JsonServiceClient("http:\\localhost:2000").Get<CheckIfConfiguredResponse>("/CheckIfConfigured");
```

Is that the proper way to go about doing it? Or is there better? 
Also, How do I eliminate having to specify the web address manually and have it automatically populate the host (since it's the same web site)

Thanks in advance,
Will.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You never want to make a HTTP call back to yourself just to call a ServiceStack service.

Unlike other frameworks, Services in ServiceStack are simply auto-wired C# types which you can access from the IOC like every other registered IOC dependency. i.e. Inside a Razor View you can simply resolve it and call it directly from the IOC with:

```
var response = base.Get<CheckIfConfiguredService>().Get(new CheckIfConfigured());
```

This resolves and calls the service like a normal auto-wired C# dependency, but doesn't inject the current request context. If your service does need it, you can instead use [AppHostBase.ResolveService](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack/WebHost.Endpoints/AppHostBase.cs#L163) which does, e.g:

```
var response = AppHostBase
  .ResolveService<CheckIfConfiguredService>(HttpContext.Current)
  .Get(new CheckIfConfigured());
```