# ServiceStack ResolveService

Tags: razor, inversion-of-control, servicestack, dto

So my problem revolves around calling apphost.ResolveService described in the url below:
[Calling a ServiceStack service from Razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962845/calling-a-servicestack-service-from-razor)

I am in my _Layout.cshtml

And obviously the following code works perfectly, but as suggested in the answer in the above url it is sort of silly

```cs
SMSGateway.Services.EntityCollectionResponse response = 
    new ServiceStack.ServiceClient.Web.JsonServiceClient(
        "http://localhost:1337/")
        .Get<SMSGateway.Services.EntityCollectionResponse>(
            "/entities");
```

So that gives me a list of Entities :) But not optimal... so here is my attempt to do it in the correct way

```
var response = ConsoleAppHost.Instance
    .ResolveService<SMSGateway.Services.EntityService>(
        HttpContext.Current).Get(
            new SMSGateway.Services.EntitiesRequest());

// SMSGateway.Services.EntityCollectionResponse response =
//     base.Get<SMSGateway.Services.EntityService>().Get(
//         new SMSGateway.Services.EntitiesRequest());

foreach (var entity in response.Result)
{
    <li>
        <a href="@entity.MetaLink.Href">
            @Html.TitleCase(entity.Name) entities
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

Okay so the error I get is the following :

> error CS0122: ConsoleAppHost is inaccessible due to its protection
>   level....

Is this expected? I was pondering if this was not a case where I might not be allowed to call this in the _Layout.cshtml file?

Further reading brought me to the article [InternalVisibleTo Testing Internal Methods in .NET 2.0](http://devlicio.us/blogs/derik_whittaker/archive/2007/04/09/internalsvisibleto-testing-internal-methods-in-net-2-0.aspx)

Which I found very interesting :P But no cigar :)

Comment: I am looking for something that allow me to uses another "RenderBody" .... Because in the _layout.cshtml I can't seem to get information/model off my services unless I call "RenderBody", and that alone allows only one model per view... so how do I give different models for my layout ? That is the reason I opted to use the JSONClient with in Razor....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend you not calling services in a Razor template. A Razor template should be used only to render some markup from a model.

The actual data access should be performed in the ServiceStack service that rendered this template. So in your case you could call another service from the operation:

```
public object Get(SomeRequestDto message)
{
    var response = this
        .ResolveService<SMSGateway.Services.EntityService>()
        .Get(new SMSGateway.Services.EntitiesRequest()
    );

    return response.Rersult;
}
```

or you might leave the container to inject the dependent service into the current service so that you don't even need to be using some service locator anti-patterns.

```
public SomeService: Service
{
    private readonly EntityService entityService;
    public SomeService(EntityService entityService)
    {
        this.entityService = entityService;
    }

    public object Get(SomeRequestDto message)
    {
        var response = this.entityService.Get(new SMSGateway.Services.EntitiesRequest()

        return response.Rersult;
    }
}
```

and then your Razor view will of course be strongly typed to the corresponding model:

```
@model IEnumerable<WhateverTheTypeOfTheResultYouWannaBeLoopingThrough>
foreach (var entity in Model)
{
    <li>
        <a href="@entity.MetaLink.Href">
            @Html.TitleCase(entity.Name) entities
        </a>
    </li>
}
```